# Multithreading in chat applications in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multithreading

I am trying to create a chat application in PHP using AJAX and javascript. When I try to post messages  in the same browser window, the messages are posted and displayed properly. But when I opened another window and tried to send message to the first window user, it does it, but when next time I post message from window 1, it posts as if it is posting from window 2 user. I am using sessions to record username, and I believe that everytime a window is loaded, the value in the session variable of user changes and it affects the behaviour of the application in all the windows. ie, username stored as session variable in window 1 is overridden by username in window 2, because both are accessing the same piece of code. And everytime AJAX tries to get new messages from database, it gets for a different user when a new window is loaded.
  I was wondering if this could be solved by Multithreading, or if there is any other way to solve this. Do chat applications require Multithreading always? It is quite confusing to me. Please help.

Comment: Note that two windows of same browser usually share cookies, therefore sesions. Use two different browsers, or two different computers to test it. There's no need for multithreading in php chat app, afaik php doesn't even have multithreading support.

Comment: In this case polling happens. When users increase polling fails to give performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate two different users who should have different sessions who are chatting with each other you can open two different browsers (for example Internet Explorer and Firefox) and log in with one user on each browser. Then the session is not shared.

As far as i know different browser windows in same browser share sessions so the later login will overwrite the first login.